# Error as "The type org.hamcrest.Matcher cannot be resolved

Tags: rest-assured

[image]

I am getting error as

> The type org.hamcrest.Matcher cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

for Rest Assured Api Testing .

Answer (score 1):

Download the hamcrest jar from the below link and place the jar in project build path.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3

This resolved the above issue for me.

Comment: Duplicate answer

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue with java project but then I have created a maven project and added below dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
          <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>`
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
```

and imported below lib:

```
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
    import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
```

so, it got resolved. But same for java project, Rest Assured 4.3.3 jar not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this --> Download the jar file manually from browser keep it aside and configure in build path > module path > click Add external jars it will resolve the issue. This might be restriction in added dependencies in maven

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have made all the recommended [static imports](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted#static-imports).

Next, '[assertThat()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.html)'  requires parameters. And RestAssured provides convenience methods so you actually don't need to use it for common asserts. So try rewriting your `then()` to something like:

```
then().
  statusCode(200).
  contentType(ContentType.JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar from below link and place it in project build path
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Still, you facing the issue
Add this Jar in Build path ->modulerpath
Add this jar
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3
And the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Only removing all dependencies of Hamcrest from pom.xml resolve this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line - test, from below dependency...it limits the scope.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove test from pom,.xml file
`<scope>test</scope>`

Answer (score -1):

Open pom.xml file and delete the line test from all the dependencies. This resolved the above issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Open pom.xml file and delete the line test from all the dependencies. This resolved the above issue for me.

Comment: test dependencies should have the test scope.